# Google Hangouts - Invites

Tags: google-hangouts

Here's my Hangout button:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
                <div class="g-hangout" data-render="createhangout"
                                        date-invites="[{id: "foo@gmail.com", invite_type: "EMAIL"}]">
</div>
```

I have a list of users on my page. When the current user clicks any of these users, I want them to be able to open a Hangout and have the clicked user join them in the hangout. I've implemented the above code, and the Hangout opens, but nothing happens as far as inviting the clicked user - `foo@gmail.com` in this case.

What exactly is supposed to happen when a clicked user is invited? Is a notification sent to their Hangouts extension? Or is a notification sent to whichever e-mail is on file?

EDIT

This screen comes up after I enter the Hangout:

[image]

However, from the Hangouts docs, it states:
"You can specify a list of people to invite to the Hangout when it starts. The list is only a suggestion to the user that starts the Hangout. Before the Hangout begins, that user will be able to skip the invite or change the list of people."

Answer (score 0):

it's basically a syntax error.
just replace "date-invites" with "data-invites" in the html tag.
like below

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
                <div class="g-hangout" data-render="createhangout"
                                        data-invites="[{id: "foo@gmail.com", invite_type: "EMAIL"}]">
</div>
```

may be you problem solve.